# VS Code return to the last cursor position from search all side-bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

in VS code you can normally use alt+left to go back to the last cursor position when your cursor is currently on an opened document. however, if you will press ctrl+shift+f (find in all) the cursor will jump to the find in all search side-bar, and to return to the last position in the document you have to use your cursor (crtl+left won't work).

is there a way to move back from the search results side-bar to the last position in the document in VS code? (in Jetbrains products, for example, esc will do the trick because the search results are actually in a modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup` will do what you want.  So you could set up a keybinding like this (in `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+left",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
  "when": "searchViewletFocus"        // probably not necessary, but safer
}
```

See [customizing keybindings](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/docs/getstarted/keybindings.md#advanced-customization) to learn how to access the `keybindings.json` file.

Comment: so i should create `keybindings.json` file in `.vscode` folder and paste this text there? because this is not working

Comment: I made an edit with a link about the keybindings.json file.